# Visa to Ireland with a European residence permit

Tags: visas, schengen, ireland

Does a russian citizen holding european residence permit need a visa to go to Ireland? 
I found that there are special conditions for family members of Union citizens, so would like to know if it applies to the described above situation.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "European residence permit". Each country issues its own residence permits, based on its own law and rules.

Comment: @HenningMakholm while that is true in the strictest sense, it is not unreasonable to refer to the residence permits issued by EU countries collectively as "European Union residence permits," and with the common shorthand of "Europe" meaning "EU," it's not much of a stretch from there to "European residence permit."  The fact that these permits are issued in a [standardized format](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32002R1030) doesn't help much in this regard.

Comment: @HenningMakholm "I have a US driving license" "No you don't! Each state issues its own driving licenses!" This is a distinction without a difference in the context of the present question.

Comment: I don't think it's pedantic. Nationality is relevant to answering the question. The question is unnecessarily vague. I assume they don't have a residence permit for Ireland.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the residence permit you hold. I also assume you mean a short-term travel.

If it is the Article 10 residence permit (must have the wording "Residence card of a family member of a Union citizen"), you can *accompany your EEA family member* on their trip to Ireland without a visa.

If you hold a national residence permit, you'll need a type C visa:

> Family members of EU/EEA/Swiss citizens seeking to reply on Directive 2004/38/EC (Free Movement Directive) – type of visa for which you should apply
>
> If you are a non-EEA national:
>
> - who does not hold a document called “Residence card of a family member of a Union citizen” as referred to in Articles 5(2) and 10(1) of Directive 2004/38/EC on the rights of citizens of the Union and their family members to move and reside freely within the territory of Member States, and
> - wishes to accompany or join an EU/EEA/Swiss citizen family member who is moving to or residing in Ireland pursuant to the Directive 2004/38/EC,
>
> You can apply for a single journey short-stay C visa which will permit you to enter and reside in the State for up to 3 months.
>
> ...
>
> If you are a ‘qualifying family member’ of an EU/EEA /Swiss Citizen you are exempt from the visa fee.

[Source](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Family+Members+of+EU_EEA+_Swiss+citizens)

Comment: My understanding is that the free of charge Type C visa issued to a qualifying family member allows the holder just to accompany their EEA family member to Ireland. For independent trips, a regular Type C visa should be obtained.

Comment: That the UK has completely different names for their analogous documents is perhaps the only aspect I have noticed in which immigration law makes more sense in the UK than it does in other EU countries.